# How to mount a partition for Home?

Tags: partitioning, mount, home-directory, fstab

I want to mount a partition for `/home` mainly so I wont need to back up next time I upgrade Ubuntu. For that reason I created a separate partition formatted as **ext4**. I have copied most of my files to the partition.

When I do
`sudo mount /dev/sda5 /home` (`sda5` taken using `lsblk`)
I can see all the files I copied using ls, including `.mozilla`, but Firefox wont find it and throw an error. Same goes for everything else. I can't really do anything that uses files until I `umount`.

I tried automatically mounting it adding a line to `/etc/fstab`:
`UUID=[UUID from blkid] /home ext4 defaults 0 2`
but **Ubuntu** or just the **GUI** seemed to crash when launching, requiring me to repeat and repeat the password without success. For some reason I could log in with guest.

I then reverted the `/etc/fstab` using **TTY**. What's strange, in **TTY** I could login without problems.

I am able to mount on locations other than `/home`. How do I mount it as `/home`?

Comment: "mainly so I wont need to back up next time I upgrade Ubuntu"  you ALWAYS need to backup before upgrading. A separate /home does not negate that.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't preserve the correct ownerships/permissions when you copied the files. Please add the outputs of `ls -ld $HOME/{,.ICEauthority,.Xauthority}` and `id`  from when you are logged in at the TTY.

Comment: You were correct, everything is owned by `root`. Do I need to do anything special to make new files owned by me (I know `chown` for old ones)? Also, feel free to add as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't preserve the correct ownerships/permissions when you copied the files.

You can check the most important file attributes by logging in to the TTY and using

```
ls -ld $HOME/{,.ICEauthority,.Xauthority}
```

If necessary, you can change the ownership back recursively using

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

If you continue to experience issues then look at the file permissions as well - but those are less likely to have been modified. If you have other users whose home directories reside on `/home` then you will likely need to correct those ownerships as well.

Comment: How should I copy files while keeping the correct ownerships?

Comment: I *think* it's usually recommended to use `cp -a` e.g. something like `cp -a -- /home/* /mnt/newhome/` - but please check

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments you should always backup your system before updating , creating. Separate home will not help that, you should use an external hard drive or a completely separate  internal hard drive, not just a partitioned one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm ok with backing up my Linux partitions, but would I need to backup all others too? Installing Ubuntu didn't affect those so neither should an upgrade, right?